# javascript/typescript function parameter syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

For the following typescript code

```
import React from 'react';
import classnames from 'classnames';
import { ClassValue } from 'classnames/types';


type Props = {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  className: ClassValue;
  tag?: React.ElementType;
  style?: React.CSSProperties;
};

const Component: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ tag: Tag, className, children, ...props }) => (
  <Tag { ...props } className={ classnames('component', className) }>
    { children }
  </Tag>
);

Component.defaultProps = {
  tag: 'div',
};

export default Component;
```

Why `<Tag` can be used but not `<tag` ? Isn't tag the parameter of the function and Tag is the type of it? What syntax being used here?

Comment: React components have to be capitalized as a convention: https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components

Comment: The type of `tag` is `React.ElementType` as you write in your code. `tag: Tag` in the props destructuring is a special JavaScript syntax that allows to rename destructured variables. This is TypeScript unrelated.

Comment: @JohannesKlauß Thanks, didn't know the rename destructured variables syntax.